# Need to convert a byte array to a transmittable String and back again (This isn't a duplicate)

Tags: java, arrays

Ok so I know this gets asked a decent amount, but this is slightly different. I have a program that takes an image file (or any input file of the user's choosing) and converts it into a byte array, which is then put into a string. However, when converting the String array (each element containing one byte) back into a byte array, it tells me that I can't convert a String (or Integer when I tried Integer.parseInt) into a byte object. Any idea what's happening?
This is an example of the string output of the bytes in the array after a file has been read in:

```
|1|1|1|0|96|0|96|0|0|-1|-37|0|67|0|2|1|1|2|1|1|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|3|5|3|3|3|3|3|6|4|4|3|5|7|6|7|7|7|6|7|7|8|9|11|9|8|8|10|8|7|7|10|13|10|10|11|12|12|12|12|7|9|14|15|13|12|14|11|12|12|12|-1|-37|0|67|1|2|2|2|3|3|3|6|3|3|6|12|8|7|8|12|12|12|12|12|12|12|12|12|12|12|12|12|12|12|
```

Yes it is properly split
Here's my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.*;

public class SmallBinaryFiles{

    public static void main(String aArgs) throws IOException{

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        SmallBinaryFiles binary = new SmallBinaryFiles();
        System.out.println("1. Send file");
        System.out.println("2. Recieve file");

        if(sc.nextInt() == 1){
            System.out.println("Name of file (with Extension and proper capitalization)");
            byte[] bytes = binary.readSmallBinaryFile(sc.nextLine());
            log("Small - size of file read in:" + bytes.length);
            for(int x = 0;x < bytes.length; x++){
                System.out.print(bytes[x] + "|");
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("Name of file to write (with extension)");
            String fileName = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please input raw data:");
            String rawData = sc.nextLine();
            String delims = "[|]+";
            String[] tempArray = rawData.split(delims);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[tempArray.length];
            for(int x = 0; x < tempArray.length;x++){
                bytes[x] = tempArray[x].toByte();
            }
            binary.writeSmallBinaryFile(bytes, fileName);
        }
    }

    byte[] readSmallBinaryFile(String aFileName) throws IOException{
        Path path = Paths.get(aFileName);
        return Files.readAllBytes(path);
    }

    void writeSmallBinaryFile(byte[] aBytes, String aFileName) throws IOException{
        Path path = Paths.get(aFileName);
        Files.write(path, aBytes);
    }

    private static void log(Object aMsg){
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(aMsg));
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!(I don't know why the code did that, sorry about that)

Comment: First, reformat this. Second, if you need to turn a `String` into a `byte[]`, then `String.getBytes()` is the right method for you.

Comment: *Why* are you converting the byte array into a string of this format? This sounds like a terrible idea. Why not just use base64?

Comment: Binary is not text

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm doing it this way so that the string can be sent over SMS or other forms of communication, as MMS only allows you to send pictures and videos, not text files or audio messages, ect.

Comment: @DYLANTAYLOR: That's not a good reason to use *this* way of converting binary data into ASCII text. Hex or base64 would be easier to read, more compact, and more easily understood by other code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, when converting the String array (each element containing one byte) back into a byte array, it tells me that I can't convert a String (or Integer when I tried Integer.parseInt) into a byte object. Any idea what's happening?

Well yes, there's no such method as `String.toByte()`, and it's not clear how you were trying to use `Integer.parseInt()`. This should work:

```
bytes[x] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(tempArray[x]);
```

This is a terrible encoding scheme though - I'd strongly urge you to use base64 or hex instead.